# Inserting values into list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying to insert values in a list which is part of while loop, instead of inserting the last value is replacing the one before, so the list will always have only one value!, I am trying to add the values not replacing them, here is my code:

```
while X != 1:
    resultList = [];
    #extList = []
    count += 1
    if X % 2:
        X = 3 * X + 1
    elif not X % 2:
        X = X // 2 #important to use double slash to have a integer division
    print(X)
    resultList.insert(count-1, X)
    #print("the resultList is " + str(resultList))

    #extList.extend(resultList)

print("The inputValue "+str(originalValue)+" took "+str(count)+" calculations to reach 1")
print (resultList)
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: `resultList.insert(count-1, X)` should be `resultList.append(X)`

Comment: `resultList = []` probably shouldn't be inside the `while`

Comment: You are writing python code like C++ code. You should use the languages powerful tools.

Comment: there are plenty of collatz related questions on SO even some with nice optimizations for computing them - if you want to go for longest till number xxx: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+collatz

Answer (score 3):

On each iteration of `while` loop you creates new instance of `resultList` list.

```
while X != 1:
    resultList = [];
...
```

should be replaced with

```
resultList = [];
while X != 1:
    ...
```

And to add new element to the end of `list` you could use `append` method. Like

```
resultList = [];
while X != 1:
    if X % 2:
        X = 3 * X + 1
    else:
        X = X // 2 #important to use double slash to have a integer division
    print(X)
    resultList.append(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while X != 1:
    resultList = [];
    #etc
```

You are re-creating the list with every iteration of the loop. Hence, it will only have one value at the end, the one given by the only insert in the final iteration.

Taking the assignment out of the loop like so:

```
resultList = [];
while X != 1:
    #etc
```

..fixes the problem.

An additional note, what you have done here is unnecessary:

```
    elif not X % 2:
    X = X // 2
```

You needn't repeat and invert your original condition. You can simply make it an `else`.

```
if X % 2:
    X = 3 * X + 1
else:
    X = X // 2
```